# Checkbox on checked make <div> become into <input> forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Is this practice possible? Like when checkbox checked change the related content into input form, so with that I can edit the information.

Comment: Short answer: yes it is posible

Comment: Is there any example I can refer to?

Comment: You explain it yourself how it's done. When the change event of the checkbox is triggered, unhide from or inject into the html an input element. So you look up the change event ( addEventListener ), then you look up the CSS code to hide a input element ( display: none ) or you look up how to add extra elements into the html. ( innerHTML or appendChild() )

Comment: You can bind an onchange event to the checkbox so when it changes you can execute a javascript that hide/show the input form or change the HTML of the div element.

Comment: Yes there are many. A [jQuery](https://jquery.com) tutorial might be a good place to start.

Comment: Before jumping around with jQuery I'd recommend to get familiar with the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) and what is possible, and what isn't. Also please consider to write a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course it is possible . Not sure about your use case , but you can achieve so here is how.

```js
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
var parent = document.getElementById("parentDiv");
parent.appendChild(input);
input.addEventListener("change", function(){
  input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  input.focus();
});

input.addEventListener("focusout", function(){
  if(input.getAttribute('type') == "text"){
    input.setAttribute('data-text', input.value)
   document.getElementById("parentDiv").innerHTML =      input.getAttribute('data-text');
   input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
   parent.appendChild(input);
  }
})
```

```css
#parentDiv{
height:150px;
width:300px;
border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parentDiv">
 <span id="placeholder">Text will be here</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the type of an element with pure javascript. But you can hide and show some input for example. Here is how you can register the event:

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox')

checkbox.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    //enable your input
  } else {
    //disable your input
  }
})
```